# What is the best way to use states in react for input variables?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hooks, use-state

I am fairly new to react
I have an input form in React Typescript and I want to use the useState hook for storing the values of name, email, and other input tags. I am using state like this :

```ts
type Props = {
    name: string,
    email: string,
    message: string,
}

const ContactMe = () => {
    const [formInputs, setFormInputs] = useState<Props>({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        message: '',
    });
    const handleData = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Is it the right approach like this or should I need to have a separate state for each input element?

Comment: Best approach is using separate state for each input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it the right approach like this or should I need to have a separate state for each input element?

You could use separate state for each input element for small form, and object for a larger form.

As you need to clone object while set new value like this way:

```
setFormInputs({
    ... formInputs,
    name: 'newName'
})
```

it may cause performance issue in a big form, I suggest to use [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for better performance